# How to solve "child_process_1.spawn is not a function" of Python-shell in Vue.js project (CLI)?

Tags: javascript, python, vue.js, runtime-error

I'm trying to run the following code in Vue.js CLI project, which executes a python file by using Python-shell (node-module):

```
methods: {
      launchPy() {
          let {PythonShell} = require('python-shell')
          PythonShell.run('my_script.py', null, function (err) {
            if (err) throw err;
              console.log('finished2');
          });
},
```

In the 'my_script.py', the following code was inserted:

```
f = open("demo.txt", "a")
f.write("Writing a file")
f.close()
```

When I run the localhost and execute the method from a botton click: launchPy(), the next error appears:

> [Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: child_process_1.spawn
> is not a function"

I have installed node.js and Python-shell already. Even when I run the exact same code of function launchPy() in a separate fileName.js file and execute the 'node fileName.js' command, it runs smoothly and indeed, the python file is executed.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Just to be clear: Vue code runs in the browser, not on the server. To run a server-side python script, you need to use ajax/fetch in your Vue app to request a backend endpoint, and the server-side script serving the endpoint can now run a Python program (also: is it annoying and confusing that npm contains both browser-only and node-only modules? yes)

Comment: Thanks! I will try this.